# How to display data inside nested repeaters with multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado

I am trying to create an Employee Shift Scheduler.
At the moment, I'm trying to display current shifts.

Below is my current output:
[image: snip1]

As you can see, there are 2 shifts on the Saturday. I want to display both of these shifts under the one header - "Saturday, 03 June 2017", rather than having duplications.

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make to my code in order to achieve this?

I have posted my current code below:

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSubscription" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repSubscription_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #3A6EA5; color: white">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <%# Eval("Start_Time", "{0:dddd, dd MMMM yyyy}") %>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <!--panel-heading-->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repShift" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <b><%# Eval("Job_Title") %></b>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    </br>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repEmp" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("Employee_Name") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repTimes" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("Start_Time", "{00:HH:MM}") %> - <%# Eval("End_Time" , "{00:HH:MM}") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

C#:

```
        `private void bindRepeater()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Start_Date, End_Date FROM My_Subscription WHERE Subscription_Id = 1", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
                startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["Start_Date"]);
                endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["End_Date"]);'

                //lblError.Text += startDate.ToString() + "<br/>" + 
    endDate.ToString();

        }
    conn.Close();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Start_Time, Emp_ID, Job_ID, Emp_Sch_Id FROM My_Employee_Schedule WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN @startReportDate AND @endReportDate", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startReportDate", startDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endReportDate", endDate);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    repSubscription.DataSource = dt;
                    repSubscription.DataBind();
                }
            }
    }
}

protected void repSubscription_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repBusiness = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repShift"));


        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Job_ID").ToString();
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Job_Title FROM My_Job_Type WHERE Job_Type_Id= '" + Group_Id + "';", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repBusiness.DataSource = dt;
        repBusiness.DataBind();
    }
    conn.Close();


    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repTimes = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repTimes"));


        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Emp_Sch_Id").ToString();
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Start_Time, End_Time FROM My_Employee_Schedule WHERE Emp_Sch_Id= '" + Group_Id + "';", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repTimes.DataSource = dt;
        repTimes.DataBind();
    }


    conn.Open();
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repEmp = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repEmp"));


        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Emp_ID").ToString();
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Employee_Name FROM My_Employee WHERE Employee_Id= '" + Group_Id + "';", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repEmp.DataSource = dt;
        repEmp.DataBind();
    }
    conn.Close();
}`
```

Comment: You need to define "not working". Are you getting an error message? Is it not returning the correct data? Also, you really need to look into parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange I'll parameterize when I get it working, I promise, I'll show you! :) When I try to run this code I get this error: _Additional information: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value._

Comment: So where does this happen? The other thing you really need to do is wrap your connection and adapter in a USING statement or your connection pool is going to run out of connections because you are not disposing of them. As for parameterizing....why not just do it now? It is hardly any extra effort. I have seen so many projects where "I will parameterize" turns into...."Oh I forgot because it was working". Just do it right from the beginning.

Comment: @SeanLange Also, I've checked what the value of Start_time is, & it appears as the following in a label: **01/06/2017 20:41:00**

Comment: That is likely to cause some issues because it is not clear what dateformat this is in. You are doing an implicit conversion here and the format could be different for different users and this format is not going to work for every culture.

Comment: @SeanLange I've parameterised above.

Comment: Is it possible to just retrieve the date (dd/MM/yyyy") for the outer repeater, and then in the nested one, display the shifts that have the same dates, but may have different times? I.e. the shifts in the nested repeater will have the same dd/MM/yyyy, but the times at the end of this column would be different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145484/discussion-between-user2911539-and-sean-lange).

Comment: @SeanLange Hi, I've made a bit of progress from yesterday. Could you have a look at this please if you have time?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with that error. Do you get the same date error when changing the below? If not, what's happening?

```
protected void repFullSchedule_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater repCurrentShift = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repCurrentShifts"));


            string Start_time = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Start_Time").ToString();
            //DateTime my_Time = DateTime.ParseExact(Start_time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Job_Type FROM Shift WHERE Start_Time=@my_Time", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_Time", Start_time);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            repCurrentShift.DataSource = dt;
            repCurrentShift.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've made some changes to the code since posting this.